# MySQL 5.0 assign number based on different column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been trying to figure out how to assign the number (in my case the group number based on the value in different column). I have a table with a number and based on that number I try to assign the group number. The number is the order of the table and it can be the same for several rows.

```
create table test (
    code varchar(10) primary key,
    num varchar(10) not null,
    name varchar(10) not null,
    surname varchar(10) not null);

insert into test values (1,9,'Tom', 'Smith');
insert into test values (2,9,'Adam','Blake');
insert into test values (3,15,'John','Smith');
insert into test values (4,15,'Adam','XYZ');
insert into test values (5,43,'John','Abc');
insert into test values (6,99,'Adam','Abc');
insert into test values (7,99,'John','Abc');
```

So the test table looks like this:

[image]

and the desired output looks like this where the grp value is always the consecutive number starting from 1.

[image]

Code for results:

```
create table result (
    code varchar(10) primary key,
    num varchar(10) not null,
    name varchar(10) not null,
    surname varchar(10) not null,
grp varchar(10) not null);

insert into result values (1,9,'Tom', 'Smith',1);
insert into result values (2,9,'Adam','Blake',1);
insert into result values (3,15,'John','Smith',2);
insert into result values (4,15,'Adam','XYZ',2);
insert into result values (5,43,'John','Abc',3);
insert into result values (6,99,'Adam','Abc',4);
insert into result values (7,99,'John','Abc',4);
```

Can this be achieved without creating any functions and variables? Are there any pseudo columns that describe it and could be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `subquery` :

```
select *, (select count(distinct t1.num) from test t1 where t1.num <= t.num) as grp
from test t;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(distinct t2.num)
        from test t2
        where t2.num <= t.num
       ) as grp
from test t;
```

A more efficient method uses variables:

```
select t.*,
       (@grp := if(@n = t.num, @grp,
                   if(@n := t.num, @grp + 1, @grp + 1)
                  )
       ) as grp
from (select t.*
      from test t
      order by t.num
     ) t cross join
     (select @grp := 0, @n := -1) params;
```

Comment: What would be the extra code if I wanted to check with the group number is even or odd (1 for even, 0 for odd number)?